# what is the relation between Node.js and Express framework

Tags: node.js, express

What I have found is that express is web framework, and Node.js is a platform, and express frame work can work on it.

Is there more explaination?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/ and http://expressjs.com/ The home pages for each tool have a short description of what each is. If you want more information than that, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Also note that express.js isn't tied to node, it can be used on platforms similar to node as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it like.

```
If javascript is equal to java.
 then 
  Node.js will be equal to Android.
  and
  express.js will be equal to Sherlock/(any library).
```

Basically, Node.js is a library that is built on top of javascript and allows you to perform server side operations.
where as, express is a library (rather say framework) which eases your task to make APIs and generating view by adding a layer of abstraction. So that you can achieve your goal easily, and timely.